# How to retrieve users post using sequalize in express?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

> I want to retrieve users post by users logged in Id with following
>   conditions. As currently I am getting user-post as null.
>
> 1: If user posted a post. same user should be able to view his post
>   (if same user is not friend with anyone i.e ACCEPTED status).
>
> 2: If user posted a post, other users with whom he is friend should be
>   able to view post.
>
> Basically I have used following database design,
>
> 1: Users id,  first Name,  last Name
>
> 2: Post id,  post
>
> 3: UserPost
>       id,
>       postId, (referencing Post table),
>       userId (referencing User table)
>
> 4: Friendship id, userId, (referencing User table) friendUserId,
>   (referencing User table) friendshipStatus (e.g values ACCEPTED,
>   REJECTED)
>
> Following is associations and query to retrieve the records schema,
>
> 1: User association

```
const Users = sequelize.define(
    'Users',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        field: 'id'
      },
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'firstName'
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
        allowNull: true,
        field: 'lastName'
      },
    {
      tableName: 'users'
    }
  );

Users.associate = models => {
    Users.hasMany(models.Friendships, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'friendship'});
    Users.hasMany(models.UserPost, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user-post' 
 }); 
}
```

> 2: Friendship association

```
const Friendships = sequelize.define(
      'Friendships',
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
          field: 'id'
        },
        userId: {
          type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
          allowNull: false,
          references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id'
          },
          field: 'userId'
        },
        friendUserId: {
          type: DataTypes.BIGINT,
          allowNull: false,
          references: {
            model: 'users',
            key: 'id'
          },
          field: 'friendUserId'
        },
        friendshipStartDate: {
          type: DataTypes.DATE,
          allowNull: true,
          field: 'friendshipStartDate'
        },
        friendshipStatusId: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
          allowNull: true,
          field: 'friendshipStatusId'
        },
      },
      {
        tableName: 'friendships'
      }
    );

Friendships.associate = models => {
     Friendships.belongsTo(models.UserPost, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user-post' });
     Friendships.belongsTo(models.Users, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'user' });      
  };
```

> 3: Post association

```
const Post = sequelize.define(
      'Post',
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
          field: 'id'
        },
        post: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
          allowNull: false,
        //   defaultValue: '0',
          field: 'Post'
        },
        postStatusId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'PostStatusId'
          },
          createdBy: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'CreatedBy'
          },
          updatedBy: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: true,
            field: 'ModifiedBy'
          }
      },
      {
        tableName: 'posts',
        updatedAt: false,
        createdAt: false
      }
    );

Post.associate = models => {
    Post.belongsTo(models.Friendships, { foreignKey:'userId', as: 'friendship' });
    Post.belongsTo(models.UserPost, { foreignKey: 'postId', as: 'userspost' });
    Post.belongsTo(models.Users, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'user' }); 
};
```

> 4: UserPost association

```
const UserPost = sequelize.define(
      'UserPost',
      {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
          field: 'id'
        },
        userId: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
          allowNull: false,
          references: {
            model: 'user',
            key: 'id' 
          },
          field: 'userId'
        },
        postId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
            allowNull: true,
            references: {
              model: 'posts',
              key: 'id' 
            },
            field: 'postId'
          }
      },
      {
        tableName: 'user_posts',
        updatedAt: false,
        createdAt: false
      }
    );

UserPost.associate = models => {
     UserPost.hasMany(models.Post, { sourceKey:'postId', foreignKey: 'id', as: 'post' });
     UserPost.hasMany(models.Friendships, { foreignKey:'userId', as: 'friend' 
  }); 
};
```

Sequlize query

```
const result = await Users.findAll({
     attributes: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName'],
     subQuery: false,
     include: [
       {
         model: Friendships,
         as: 'friendship',
         attributes: ['userId', 'friendUserId'],
         where: 
             { 
               [Op.or]: {
                 userId: userId,
                 friendUserId: userId
              },
               [Op.and]: {
               friendshipStatusId: 'ACCEPT'
             }
           },
           include: [{
             model: UserPost,
             as: 'user-post',
             attributes: ['userId', 'postId'],
             subQuery: false,
               include: [
               {
                 model: Post,
                 as: 'post',
                 attributes:['id','post'],
               }
             ],
           }]         
       }
     ] })
```

> But in this query I am not getting users post records since there is
>   one entry in database of user post. following is actual result for
>   above query.

Response

```
[
     {
         "id": 5,
         "firstName": "Abc",
         "lastName": "Xyz",
         "friendship": [
             {
                 "userId": 5,
                 "friendUserId": 6,
                 "user-post": null
             }
         ]
     }
 ]
```

> do anyone having solution for this?

Comment: Can you add model definitions to the post as well?

Comment: added model definitions. please check.

Comment: Ok. First I don't get it how Friendship model is related to Post? Friendship is all about how users connected to each other, right? Second, why you have UserPost model? Does Post have several creators? If not then you should simply add user_id to Post model.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we're on the same page, from features perspective you want users to be able to be friends with each others and posts created by a user can only be seen by that user and his friend.

From the relations perspective by UserPost you want to get all the users who have access to a post.

If this is correct then the way to go about it is much simpler.

First you don't need a many-to-many relation between user and post(UserPost) since you don't need many users to belong to a post unless a post can have multiple creators.

From raw database tables perspective we want(minimal):

User:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| firstName | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastName  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Friendship:

```
+-----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int                                 | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| status    | enum('PENDING','ACCEPTED','DENIED') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt | datetime                            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime                            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_1    | int                                 | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_2    | int                                 | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Post:

```
+-----------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int                      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content   | varchar(1000)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status    | enum('ACTIVE','DELETED') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| createdAt | datetime                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updatedAt | datetime                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| UserId    | int                      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Which in sequelize can be done with:

```
const User = sequelize.define('User',{
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: true,
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
            allowNull: true,
        }
})

User.associate = models => {
    User.hasMany(models.Friendship, { foreignKey: "user_1" });
    User.hasMany(models.Friendship, { foreignKey: "user_2" });
};
const Post = sequelize.define('Post',{
        content: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
            allowNull: false,
        },
        status: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM("ACTIVE", "DELETED"),
            allowNull: false,
            default: "ACTIVE"
        }
    }
);

Post.associate = models => {
    Post.belongsTo(models.User);
};
const Friendship = sequelize.define('Friendship', {
    status: {
        type: DataTypes.ENUM("PENDING", "ACCEPTED", "DENIED"),
        allowNull: false,
        default: "PENDING"
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
const models = require("./models")
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

const { User, Friendship, Post } = models;

const requestPost = async (user_id,post_id) => {
    let user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: user_id } })
    let post = await Post.findOne({ where: { id: post_id }, include: [User] })
    let isFriend = await Friendship.findOne({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                {
                    user_1: user.id,
                    user_2: post.User.id,
                    status: "ACCEPTED"
                },
                {
                    user_1: post.User.id,
                    user_2: user.id,
                    status: "ACCEPTED"
                }
            ]
        }
    })
    if (isFriend) return post;
}


let run = async () => {
    await models.sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    let user1 = await User.create({
        firstName: "dummy1",
        lastName: "dummy1"
    })
    let user2 = await User.create({
        firstName: "dummy2",
        lastName: "dummy2"
    })
    let user3 = await User.create({
        firstName: "dummy3",
        lastName: "dummy3"
    })
    let user1_user2_friendship_accepted = await Friendship.create({
        user_1: user1.id,
        user_2: user2.id,
        status: "ACCEPTED"
    })
    let user1_user3_friendship_pending = await Friendship.create({
        user_1: user1.id,
        user_2: user3.id,
    })
    let user1_post = await Post.create({
        UserId: user1.id,
        content: "Dummy-content"
    })

    // Example 1:
    // user2 wants to access user1_post:
    let getPost1 = await requestPost(user2.id, user1_post.id) // returns post
    // Example 2:
    // user3 wants to access user1_post:
    let getPost2 = await requestPost(user3.id, user1_post.id) // returns undefined

    console.log("\n\n\n\n")
    if (getPost1) console.log("Returned getPost1")
    if (getPost2) console.log("Returned getPost2")
}

run()
```